# Use regex to validate a phone number?

Tags: java, regex, validation, if-statement

```
if((phone.length() > 10 && 
                    ((phone.contains("+1" + "((\\\\d{3}-)){1,2}\\\\d{4}")) 
                    || (phone.contains("+966" + "d{9}"))))
                    || ((phone.length() == 10) && 
                    !(phone.contains("(") && !(phone.contains(")") &&
                    !(phone.contains("-")))))) //phone doesnt contain special characters if its a saudi no.
                {
                    ....
                }
                else {
                    ....
                }
```

Hello all :) I'm trying to create a code that validates the following formats of phone numbers and NOTHING else:

1. +9665xxxxxxxx
2. 05xxxxxxxx
3. +1(xxx)xxx-xxxx
4. +1xxxxxxxxxx
5. xxx-xxx-xxxx

I've tried to do this in the code above, where the phone number is represented as String "phone". However I think I've done it incorrectly, especially the regex. Can anyone tell me if there is a simpler way to do this? Or a simplified version of the code? Would it be easier if I used a series of if() statements instead? I'm sorry I'm very new to java so I'm sure I've done something wrong.

Comment: When you say *validate*, do you mean that the number simply needs to match one of those five patterns to be considered valid, or does it need to represent an actual, genuine phone number? One is harder than the other

Comment: @JonK what do you mean by the second part? because i just meant it had to fit into the pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "\\+9665\\d{8}|05\\d{8}|\\+1\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}-\\d{4}|\\+1\\d{10}|\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}"
);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("+966512345678");
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

Comment: thank you very much! can i please know how you learned to do this?

Comment: The javadoc is a good start https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html